# How do I revert to latest external snapshot in KVM?

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, snapshot, libvirt

I have created an external snapshot with KVM using

```
virsh snapshot-create-as domain --name snap1 --disk-only
```

Then, I started the domain with “`virsh start domain`”.  I know that reverting to external snapshots is not yet implemented (at least not in RHEL7) and there is the possibility to do it manually by editing XML and using `qemu-ing`.  But all HOWTOS that I've found are vague or doubtful or both.

So, how to you throw away the current overlay and return to the latest snapshot, starting a fresh overlay on top of it?

What I've found so far:

- [quasi-official workaround](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/I_created_an_external_snapshot,_but_libvirt_will_not_let_me_delete_or_revert_to_it): This is linked to by RedHat's documentation.  I find this very complicated and without concrete instructions.
- [answer on Stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/677099/revert-libvirt-external-snapshot): This is vague.  What should I change in the XML file?  How do I cleanly remove the overlay?
- [Linux Mint Forums post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213382): This is at least slightly helpful for me.  But why should I change the file type to “raw”?  Besides, this doesn't seem to start a fresh overlay on top of the latest snapshot but instead append changes to the overlay before the current one, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

After taking a live external snapshot with `--atomic` the `libvirt` xml will be something like:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/srv/qemu/images/proxmox4-node2.pre_upgrade'/>
  <backingStore type='file'>
    <format type='qcow2'/>
    <source file='/srv/qemu/images/proxmox4-node2.qcow2'/>
  </backingStore>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <boot order='1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

To revert the `vm` back simply `virsh edit my_domain` to:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/srv/qemu/images/proxmox4-node2.qcow2'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <boot order='1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```